# How can I make my XNA game available for play?

Tags: c#, xna

I have just completed my game with C# XNA 4.0 and when I compile and run it works perfectly.

I just have 1 question. What do I do next to package it all up and make it uploadable so people can download and play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered throughly on the MSDN page [**Distributing Your Finished Windows Game**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464156.aspx). Especially if you just want to use the simple, standard ClickOnce method of distribution.

The page [**Packing and Distributing Your Game**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417502.aspx) has info if you're not doing a normal Windows distribution.

If you're looking for a bit more info, [this answer here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/426/feasibility-of-an-xna-game-on-pc/462#462) is probably worth reading.

Comment: Thanks for the links, Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

for what? Windows Phone 7? Xbox?

go to: http://create.msdn.com for all the info you need on distribution

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use it on Xbox, try:
[Create game for xbox](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/)
or [Creator's Club](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/XNA-Creators-Club/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802584e07d1)
You will need a creator's club membership to post games on Xbox. Also, remember to change the input of you project to:

```
GamePadState gPad = GamePad.GetState();
if (gPad.Triggers.Left > 0.5)
{
    //Game pad trigger is pressed
}
```